# Open code editor using Bash in Cloud Shell to edit files stored in Azure using VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, command, azure-cloud-shell

I'm using VS Code and I'm logged in to my azure account using Bash in Cloud Shell.

Once I'm in the storage directory, I want to open and code some of those files and for that, I type the command "code ." however it does not seem to work.

On the other hand, when using https://shell.azure.com/ I'm able to type that same command and open and edit the files.

Does anyone know why it's not working in VS code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the code tool in the cloud shell when you use the browser is the VS code itself with limited features. You can see the released document [Announcing the Azure Cloud Shell editor in collaboration with Visual Studio Code](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cloudshelleditor/). It just wants to enable a strong simple utility that can be accessed from any browser. And it seems you cannot open the code tool in code itself. You can also see some more details [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/07/20/azure-cloud-shell.aspx).

So I recommend if you want to use the code tool in the cloud shell, just use it in the browser.